# Magento 1.9 get product status (1 or 2) programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

What is the way to get a product status programatically?

I've tried

```
  $_status = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->getProductStatus($productID);
```

and

```
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
  $_status = $_product->getData('status');
```

but none of the above is working.
what did I miss?

Comment: Did you print it ?

Comment: I tried to use javascript alert, and it shown "native code" in the popup box.

Comment: Please paste full code here

Comment: please try to print $product->getData() and paste here @Sun

Comment: It's working now. I need to set a storeId...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying setting storeId.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(1)->load(1);
```

To Get Status

```
$product->getStatus()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check the status of product by `Magento` `getter` method or from `getData('status')`, like below

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('1');

$product->getStatus() // getter method

$product->getData('status'); // getData() method
```